# Object doesn't support property or method 'startRequest' + rs.htm

Tags: asp-classic

In one of my legacy application which was developed using classic asp, remote scripting was implemented using rs.htm.

It is working fine in IE11. But it is not working in chrome and edge browser. I am getting an error as "*Object doesn't support property or method 'startRequest'*" for the below line

```
this.rsapplet.startRequest(request.id,url_context,url,this.REQUEST_MODE_COMPLETE);
```

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `rs.htm`?  It look like an client side applet (java, silverlight, ...)? Can you post more than 1 line?  We need more context to understand the issue.

Comment: Because `rsapplet` is likely an ActiveX control or Java applet which won't work in a non-IE browser (including Edge).

Comment: It is Remote scripting with JavaScript and ASP. For more explanation please refer the [link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/remotecode.shtml)

Comment: I've found the file rs.htm and taken a look.  It basically consists of Javascript functions which were designed to work in IE4 and Netscape 4 and which may not be compatible with modern browsers.  It also adds the `<applet>` tag to the rendered code. Modern browsers don't support the java plugin, so I'm afraid that your legacy application is pretty much obsolete.

Comment: The application using RSExecute method. Can I use either JQuery Ajax or XMLHttpRequest instead of that code?

Comment: @Kattesang - probably, I haven't read every line of it and I'm not going to, but Ajax and HTML5 have pretty well removed the need to run applets or flash animations, so I'm sure you can find an alternative